# Node.js + Express passing an object

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a small node.js/express project and have a function in configure.js that sets configuration options in my express app. For example:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var server = ('./configure');

var app = express();
server.configure(app);
```

configure.js

```
exports.configure = function(app) {
  app.set('title', 'Server');
};
```

This doesn't work but I hope it explains what I'm trying to do. I want to make changes to the app instance in server.js. How do I do this?

EDIT:

Okay I think i can get this all working if i understand why this isn't working. Is it to do with timing of the callback? The second console.log() isn't called.

configure.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');


function configure(app) {

  var config = module.exports = {};

    fs.readFile('config.txt', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      config.title = decoder.write(data)
      console.log(config.title)

    });

    if(config.title) console.log(config.title);
    //app.set('title', config.title)
}

module.exports = function (app) {
  configure(app);
};
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cfg = require('./configure');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express()

cfg(app)
```

(config.txt is echo 'server' > config.txt)

Answer (score 1):

What you have should actually work.

As for your question about using multiple functions, you can export and call each separately. This can be useful when timing is important (such as if other setup steps need to occur that aren't specified in `configure.js`):

```
// configure.js

exports.configure = function (app) {
  // ...
};

exports.attachMiddlware = function (app) {
  // ...
};
```

```
// server.js

var express = require('express');
var server = require('./configure');

var app = express();
server.configure(app);
server.attachMiddlware(app);
```

You can also define a single entry `function` as the [exported object](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) which calls the functions needed within `configure.js`. This can possibly keep `server.js` cleaner by isolating the maintenance within `configure.js`:

```
function configure(app) {
  // ...
}

function attachMiddleware(app) {
  // ...
}

module.exports = function (app) {
  configure(app);
  attachMiddleware(app)
};
```

```
var express = require('express');
var configure = require('./configure');

var app = express();
configure(app);
```

Comment: Thanks, the original issues were typos so i've edited it all out to make it easier for other people viewing this problem. What if the function is one of many within configure.js that i want to pass the app object to?

Comment: @user1786588 Ah. Updated my answer for your edit and follow-up question.

Comment: I managed to come up with what is in the EDIT above but it's not setting the config.title, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user1786588 Yes, it has to do with timing. [`fs.readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback) is asynchronous, so it will exit (`return`) immediately and the callback will be called sometime later. Also note that you're attempting to set `module.exports` twice -- once for `config` and once for the `function`. You'll want to pick one or the other and develop accordingly; or use separate modules (script files) for each.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid that and just do a json object:

app.js

```
var cfg = require('./config');
app.set('title', cfg.title);
```

config.js

```
var config = module.exports = {};
config.title = 'Server';
```